# Is there a way to have a gpio output 1 when two nodes are outputting 1 into it?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, node-red

I'm working on a security system with my raspberry pi and node-red. I have an infrared sensor outputting 1 when motion is detected, 0 when no motion is detected. I also have a switch with the pallete node-red-dashboard that outputs 1 when it is "open" and 0 when "closed". I want to make a function that would output 1 when both of the inputs are 1, kind of like an and gate. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve what you want. Import the flow below and see if it behaves like you want.

[Credits to Cory Guyyn](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-red/AoA0CAgM-M8/discussion)

```
[{"id":"326ee761.191508","type":"tab","label":"Flow 6","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"aa420627.bdb3e8","type":"function","z":"326ee761.191508","name":"Flow On/Off","func":"var state = context.get(\"state\") || \"on\";\n\n// Display initial state status\nif(state ==\"on\"){\n    node.status({fill:\"green\",shape:\"dot\",text:state});\n}else{\n    node.status({fill:\"red\",shape:\"ring\",text:state});\n}\n\nif(msg.topic == \"state\"){\n    context.set(\"state\",msg.payload);\n    state = msg.payload;\n    // update status\n    if(state == \"on\"){\n        node.status({fill:\"green\",shape:\"dot\",text:state});\n    }else{\n        node.status({fill:\"red\",shape:\"ring\",text:state});\n    }\n}else{\n    if(state == \"on\"){\n        return msg;\n    }\n}\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":570,"y":340,"wires":[["6968506.c5da8b"]]},{"id":"d1c0dabc.ff33f8","type":"ui_switch","z":"326ee761.191508","name":"","label":"Dynamic Input","group":"efb0cd04.2f1fe","order":0,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"state","style":"","onvalue":"on","onvalueType":"str","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"off","offvalueType":"str","officon":"","offcolor":"","x":500,"y":240,"wires":[["aa420627.bdb3e8"]]},{"id":"fb35a101.734b3","type":"inject","z":"326ee761.191508","name":"","topic":"state","payload":"on","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"x":280,"y":220,"wires":[["d1c0dabc.ff33f8"]]},{"id":"7f455eab.e11b4","type":"inject","z":"326ee761.191508","name":"","topic":"state","payload":"off","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":270,"y":260,"wires":[["d1c0dabc.ff33f8"]]},{"id":"6968506.c5da8b","type":"debug","z":"326ee761.191508","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":750,"y":340,"wires":[]},{"id":"38c4ee82.f54e92","type":"comment","z":"326ee761.191508","name":"Sample Flow Toggle with UI and Link input","info":"","x":300,"y":120,"wires":[]},{"id":"5fb3fc9b.523764","type":"inject","z":"326ee761.191508","name":"PIR - 0","topic":"","payload":"0","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":270,"y":340,"wires":[["aa420627.bdb3e8"]]},{"id":"a1e5b421.b65e08","type":"inject","z":"326ee761.191508","name":"PIR - 1","topic":"","payload":"1","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":270,"y":380,"wires":[["aa420627.bdb3e8"]]},{"id":"efb0cd04.2f1fe","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Flow Toggle","tab":"6dfbaaa8.8cfbb4","disp":true,"width":"6"},{"id":"6dfbaaa8.8cfbb4","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Sandbox","icon":"dashboard"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the code and it worked perfectly!